# Advantage of PHP SoapClient classmap

Tags: php, soap, soap-client

Can anyone tell me the advantage of using the classmap option within PHP Soapclient? Maybe with some practical examples?

Answer (score 7):

The classmap option can be used to map some WSDL types to PHP classes.

Example,

```
class MyLoginResult {
    protected $serverUrl;
    protected $sessionId;

    public function getServerUrl()
    {
         return $this->serverUrl;
    }

    public function getSessionId()
    {
        return $this->sessionId;
    }

    public function getServerInstance()
    {
        $match = preg_match(
            '/https:\/\/(?<instance>[^-]+)\.example\.com/',
            $this->serverUrl,
            $matches
        );

        return $matches['instance'];
    }
}

$client = new SoapClient("books.wsdl", 
                 array('classmap' => array('LoginResult' => "MyLoginResult")));

$loginResult = $client->getLoginResult();
$instance = $loginResult->getServerInstance();
```

Answer (score 0):

As addition to the comment by hoangthienan, I would show one more advantage when using a mapped class.

E.g. you could extend the class by a [__set()](https://www.php.net/manual/de/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.set) method, that would be triggered when the SoapClient passes its data to the mapped class (you should know, the method will not be triggered if your property is public).

In that case you can alternate the data passed from SoapClient before you assign it to your Data-Class.

```php
class MyLoginResult {
    protected $serverUrl;
    protected $sessionId;
    private $is_logged_in;


    public function __set($name, $value) {
        if ($name == 'login_status') {
            $this->is_logged_in = ($value == 'logged_in') ? true : false;            
        } else {
          $this->$name = $value;
        }
    }

    public function loginSuccessfull() {
      return $this->is_logged_in;
    }
    // class code from hoangthienan
}
```

e.g. in this example we get a string from Soap, but we store a bool-value in our class.
You could use this for other changes to e.g. if you like to store your internal variables in a array instead of using direct properties.